# Appium 1.3.7 not launching android emulator when appium started with separate method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, appium, selenium-chromedriver

Using
appium 1.3.7
appium_lib 6.0.0
ruby 2.0.0p451
chromedriver 2.15.322448
watir-webdriver 0.6.10 (from gem list)
selenium-webdriver 2.45.0 (from gem list)
Win 7 Enterprise 64bit SP 1

This works:

```
def run
    end_processes('adb.exe', 'node.exe', 'emulator-arm.exe', 'emulator-x86.exe')

    # start_appium
    debug_to_log("#{Dir.pwd.chomp}")
    log_file = File.join(Dir.pwd.chomp, 'log', "#{@myName}_appium_#{@start_timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}.log")
    command  = "appium --log-timestamp --log #{log_file}"
    debug_to_log(command)
    appium = IO.popen(command) 
    debug_to_log("Appium PID: #{appium.pid}")
    3.times { debug_to_log(appium.readline.chomp) }

    browser = open_browser_mobile("", "android emulator")
    debug_to_log("#{browser.driver.capabilities.to_yaml}")

    go_to_url(browser, "https://hxbbfb75.etforge.com/2.6.0rc6/examples/index.html")
    . . .
    browser.close if browser
    end_processes('adb.exe', 'node.exe', 'emulator-arm.exe', 'emulator-x86.exe')
end

def open_browser_mobile(device_id, device_type, ios_version='8.1')

    desired_caps = set_mobile_capabilties(device_id, device_type, ios_version)

    server_url     = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"
    client         = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
    client.timeout = 300
    debug_to_log(desired_caps.to_yaml)
    Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, # :remote,
                   :url                  => server_url,
                   :desired_capabilities => desired_caps,
                   :http_client          => client
    )
end
```

This does not:

```
def start_appium
    debug_to_log("#{Dir.pwd.chomp}")
    log_file = File.join(Dir.pwd.chomp, 'log', "#{@myName}_appium_#{@start_timestamp.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}.log")
    command  = "appium --log-timestamp --log #{log_file}"
    debug_to_log(command)
    appium = IO.popen(command) # --log-no-colors --log-timestamp  --log appium_log.txt  , :err => :out
    debug_to_log("Appium PID: #{appium.pid}")
    3.times { debug_to_log(appium.readline.chomp) }
    appium
end

def run
  end_processes('adb.exe', 'node.exe', 'emulator-arm.exe', 'emulator-x86.exe')

  start_appium

  browser = open_browser_mobile("", "android emulator")
  . . .
end
```

The appium start code is identical... if it is enclosed in a method and called, webdriver tries to start right away and fails with ECONNREFUSED. If the code is inside the same method where webdriver is started, it waits for the appium server to launch the emulator, waits for the browser to open, etc... behaving correctly.

The appium log in the failing instance is this (in entirety). Note that it ends prematurely, i.e. without showing the error at all:

```
2015-04-09 22:16:05:916 - info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.7 (REV 72fbfaa)
2015-04-09 22:16:05:917 - info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
2015-04-09 22:16:05:919 - info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"log":"C:/projects/wria2/wf2/src/wf2-automation/tests/automation/log/appium_demo_appium_20150409151600.log","logTimestamp":true}
2015-04-09 22:16:05:919 - info: Console LogLevel: debug
2015-04-09 22:16:05:919 - info: File LogLevel: debug

When it succeeds the log looks like this:
2015-04-09 22:17:46:068 - info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.7 (REV 72fbfaa)
2015-04-09 22:17:46:069 - info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
2015-04-09 22:17:46:071 - info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"log":"C:/projects/wria2/wf2/src/wf2-automation/tests/automation/log/appium_demo_appium_20150409151740.log","logTimestamp":true}
2015-04-09 22:17:46:071 - info: Console LogLevel: debug
2015-04-09 22:17:46:071 - info: File LogLevel: debug
2015-04-09 22:17:46:269 - info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"newCommandTimeout":600,"androidDeviceReadyTimeout":420,"avdLaunchTimeout":240000,"avdReadyTimeout":240000,"deviceName":"My_device","platformName":"Android","avd":"poc","browserName":"Browser","avdArgs":"-no-audio -http-proxy 151.151.15.250:8080 -dns-server 10.27.206.11:55,10.27.206.101:55,10.91.218.197:55","chromeOptions":{"args":["ignore-certificate-errors=true","homepage=about:blank","test_type=true"]},"chrome.switches":["ignore-certificate-errors=true","homepage=about:blank","test_type=true"]}}
2015-04-09 22:17:46:271 - info: Client User-Agent string: Ruby
2015-04-09 22:17:46:271 - warn: Converting cap chrome.switches to string, since it was an object. This might be a user error. Original value was: ["ignore-certificate-errors=true","homepage=about:blank","test_type=true"]
2015-04-09 22:17:46:272 - info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : androidDeviceReadyTimeout, chromeOptions, chrome.switches
2015-04-09 22:17:46:272 - info: Set mode: Proxying straight through to Chromedriver
2015-04-09 22:17:46:272 - info: [debug] Looks like we want chrome on android
2015-04-09 22:17:46:274 - info: [debug] Creating new appium session f4f658ba-0a0a-490b-af34-cadbac51aeb7
2015-04-09 22:17:46:275 - info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
2015-04-09 22:17:46:277 - info: [debug] Using adb from C:\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
2015-04-09 22:17:46:278 - info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
2015-04-09 22:17:46:278 - info: [debug] Preparing device for session
2015-04-09 22:17:46:278 - info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
2015-04-09 22:17:46:278 - info: [debug] Trying to find poc emulator
2015-04-09 22:17:46:279 - info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
2015-04-09 22:17:46:279 - info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
2015-04-09 22:17:46:280 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
2015-04-09 22:17:50:541 - info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected
2015-04-09 22:17:50:541 - info: [debug] 0 emulator(s) connected
2015-04-09 22:17:50:542 - info: [debug] Launching Emulator with AVD poc, launchTimeout 240000ms and readyTimeout 240000ms
2015-04-09 22:17:50:542 - info: [debug] Checking whether emulator is present
2015-04-09 22:17:50:547 - info: [debug] Using emulator from C:\android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe
2015-04-09 22:17:50:591 - info: [debug] Trying to find poc emulator
2015-04-09 22:17:50:591 - info: [debug] Getting connected emulators
2015-04-09 22:17:50:591 - info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
2015-04-09 22:17:50:592 - info: [debug] executing cmd: C:\android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have Appium, so this is a bit of a guess, but try waiting for the command to finish:

```
appium = IO.popen(command) 
Process.wait(appium.pid)
```

I believe you need to do this because:

- `IO.popen` does not wait for the subprocess to finish.
- The time to start Appium is greater than the time to finish the `start_appium` method and garbage collect the created IO.

Comment: be interesting to see if this works..  the other thing to try would be to maybe do the browser startup inside the start method, and have it return the browser object?